# Add column names to expand.grid

Tags: r

I have 100 variables that I need to examine with all possible combinations.

Say `root, SSID, kuku, pupu` .....

```
variables <- list(root, SSID, kuku, pupu, ...)
```

I am using the `expand.grid(variables)`

But I want the column names of the `expand.grid` to be the same as var names.

I am aware of the `set_names()` function, but maybe there is an option to avoid setting the names manually.

Please advise how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can store the vector as columns in data frame instead of `list` to avoid rewriting the names again

```
variables <- data.frame(root, SSID, ...)
expand.grid(variables)
```

With the reproducible data,

```
variables <- data.frame(a, b)
expand.grid(variables)

#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 4
#3 3 4
#4 1 5
#5 2 5
#6 3 5
#7 1 6
#8 2 6
#9 3 6
```

---

OR we can also create a named `list` instead

```
variables <- list(root = root, SSID = SSID, ...)
```

and then use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(variables)
```

With the reproducible data,

```
variables <- list(a = a, b = b)
expand.grid(variables)

#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 4
#3 3 4
#4 1 5
#5 2 5
#6 3 5
#7 1 6
#8 2 6
#9 3 6
```

**data**

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c(4:6)
```